# How to assign a new columns where value are a set of column names based on multiple columns by pandas?

Tags: pandas

I want to assign a column('Name') where value is a set of column names(A/B/C) when value is 1. The result as I want as below:

df:

```
  A   B   C  Name
1 1   0   1   {A,B}
2 0   1   0   {B}
3 1   1   1   {A,B,C}
```

Notice: the values of columns A/B/C is either 1 or 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with filtering and convert to `set`s:

```
df['Name'] = df.apply(lambda x: set(x.index[x == 1]), axis=1)
```

Or list with set comprehension:

```
df['Name'] = [set([k for k, v in x.items() if v]) for x in df.to_dict('r')]
```

Or use dot product by [`DataFrame.dot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html), with [`Series.str.rstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html), [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and convert to `set`s:

```
df['Name'] = df.dot(df.columns + ',').str.rstrip(',').str.split(',').apply(set)
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C       Name
1  1  0  1     {A, C}
2  0  1  0        {B}
3  1  1  1  {A, C, B}
```